# Why can I use an alias name as name for identifiers?

Tags: c, alias, typedef

Why does C allow to declare a pointer from type `student` (`student` being the result of a `typedef`) with the name of `student`?

```
typedef struct
{
    char* name;
    int age;
}
student;

student s = {"Mark", 22};
student* student = &s;
printf("%i\n", student->age);
```

Why does the previous code work, while the following doesn't?

```
int x = 3;
int* int = &x
printf("%i\n", *int);
```

Comment: The first block of code will work only on some compilers. Others will report error. Anyway - you should not do this. The reason you cannot defined 'int' is that 'int' is a reserved keyword of the C/C++ language. You cannot define reserved keywords yourself and cannot redefine existing keywords. This is due to the fact that a keyword is a property of C/C++ language and not a property of your code.

Answer (score 3):

You are using a reserved keyword `int` as a variable name. Use something else and it will work.

```
int x = 2 ;
int *y = &x ;
printf("%d", *y);
```

Notice that no keywords can be used a variable names or function names.

Edit : Your code for the student type will give an error : [See Here](http://ideone.com/HuV7n7) 
The error clearly says `'student' redeclared as different kind of symbol`

Comment: then why is "student" not a reserved keyword after that typedef?

Comment: I have a variant that compiles, [look here](http://ideone.com/DJX7TH), why does declaring it as a global variable works?

Comment: @Peter You can't define keywords. `typedef` defines type *aliases*.